# Is 'base64_encode' working good with videos in php?

Tags: php

I have a privet forms to give courses online that users can register and watching the video course Online after payment , And I need to produce the video without showing the original URL source by using this function :

```
// Get video view tag
function GetVideoViewTag(&$fld, $val, $tooltip = false)
{
    global $Page;
    if (!EmptyString($val)) {
        $val = $fld->htmlDecode($val);
        if ($fld->DataType == DATATYPE_BLOB) {
            $wrknames = [$val];
            $wrkfiles = [$val];
        } elseif ($fld->UploadMultiple) {
            $wrknames = explode(Config("MULTIPLE_UPLOAD_SEPARATOR"), $val);
            $wrkfiles = explode(Config("MULTIPLE_UPLOAD_SEPARATOR"), $fld->htmlDecode($fld->Upload->DbValue));
        } else {
            $wrknames = [$val];
            $wrkfiles = [$fld->htmlDecode($fld->Upload->DbValue)];
        }
        $multiple = (count($wrkfiles) > 1);
        $href = $tooltip ? "" : $fld->HrefValue;
        $isLazy = $tooltip ? false : IsLazy();
        $tags = "";
        $wrkcnt = 0;
        foreach ($wrkfiles as $wrkfile) {
            $tag = "";
            if (
                $Page && ($Page->TableType == "REPORT" &&
                ($Page->isExport("excel") && Config("USE_PHPEXCEL") ||
                $Page->isExport("word") && Config("USE_PHPWORD")) ||
                $Page->TableType != "REPORT" && ($Page->CustomExport == "pdf" || $Page->CustomExport == "email"))
            ) {
                $fn = GetFileTempImage($fld, $wrkfile);
            } else {
                $fn = GetFileUploadUrl($fld, $wrkfile, $fld->Resize);
            }
            $fi = base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/onlincu/files/'.$wrkfile));
                if ($href == "" && !$fld->UseColorbox) {
                    if ($fn != "") {
                        if ($isLazy) {
                           $tag = '<center><video style="width: 100%; height: 380px;" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,'.$fi.'" type="video/mp4" data-src="' . $fn . '"' . $fld->viewAttributes() . '></video></center>';
                         } else {
                           $tag = '<center><video style="width: 100%; height: 380px;" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,'.$fi.'" type="video/mp4" data-src="' . $fn . '"' . $fld->viewAttributes() . '></video></center>';
                         }
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($fld->UploadMultiple && ContainsString($href, '%u')) {
                        $fld->HrefValue = str_replace('%u', GetFileUploadUrl($fld, $wrkfile), $href);
                    }
                    if ($fn != "") {
                        if ($isLazy) {
                            $tag = '<center><video style="width: 100%; height: 380px;" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,'.$fi.'" type="video/mp4" data-src="' . $fn . '"' . $fld->viewAttributes() . '></video></center>';
                        } else {
                            $tag = '<center><video style="width: 100%; height: 380px;" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,'.$fi.'" type="video/mp4" data-src="' . $fn . '"' . $fld->viewAttributes() . '></video></center>';
                         }
                    }
                }
            if ($tag != "") {
                if ($multiple) {
                    $tags .= '<div class="p-1">' . $tag . '</div>';
                } else {
                    $tags .= $tag;
                }
            }
            $wrkcnt += 1;
        }
        if ($multiple && $tags != "") {
            $tags = '<div class="d-flex flex-row">' . $tags . '</div>';
        }
        return $tags;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now my function working Good even better until now , But I have read that using 'base64_encode' for videos maybe damage the original video , Well if that true What the better solution for this case ?

I appreciate your help .

Comment: `$fi = base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/onlincu/files/'.$wrkfile));` is going to use an excessive/costly amount of memory and possibly crash the viewers browser if your serving videos, making user wait for page load and placing 300mb in base64 string in browser wont work well

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I only produce one video in each time at single page , but the video file could be have large size , is this could make browsers crashing ? ,, thanks for your replay

Comment: _“But I have read that using 'base64_encode' for videos maybe damage the original video”_ - nah, that’s not true (provided you use it correctly.) But base64 encoding will increase the data size by around 4/3, which especially with videos, which are usually larger files to begin with, might be problematic. Instead of using base64 to inline the video data, it should probably rather be served by a script. (But then you might need to implement _range requests_ as well, if searching in the video without downloading the complete file first is supposed to work properly.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanx for your Advice , So what I understand now that using encrypt 'base64_encode' may could facing some programatic crash especially with large video files even when I produce one video in each time at single page ,,,

Comment: Yes, make a test script and see how it performs, `<?php echo '<!-- '.base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/512MB.zip')).' -->'` placing large amounts of data on the dom is slow loading and most likely not going to work or crash hang most browsers, especially on mobile devices which is more than 85% of most user bases. You should just use a access token or session to access the videos, the path in a url be it `/video/abc123` or `/onlincu/files/foo.mp4` is not insecure, the issue is preventing accessing videos unless paid, which can be done with auth

Comment: btw, `<center>` tag is deprecated

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i have found another solution to this my anwser bellow , is this good one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this it's worked for me but I wonder if this a good secure solution ?
so what I do that instead of using 'base64_encode' to encrypt my video URL source ,I tried to add this class bellow :

```
<?php
//VideoStream.php

class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $iv = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;
 
    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->$iv = str_repeat('z', 16);
        $this->path = openssl_decrypt($filePath, "aes128", session_id(),0,$this->$iv);
    }
     
    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }
         
    }
     
    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");        
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, private");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);
         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
  
            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;
 
            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];
                 
                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  
         
    }
    
    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }
     
    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }
     
    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}
```

And my response_video.php :

```
<?php
//response_video.php

header("location: /onlincu/");
session_start();
// Start the session
if(isset($_GET["video_id"])&& isset($_GET["token"])){
       $token_id = $_GET["token"];
       $Vid_id = $_GET["video_id"];
       $iv = str_repeat('z', 16);
       $token = openssl_decrypt($Vid_id, "aes128", $token_id,0,$iv);
       $path = openssl_encrypt("files/".$token, "aes128", session_id(),0,$iv);
       require_once'VideoStream.php';
       $stream = new VideoStream($path);
       $stream->start();
}
?>
```

Finally I call my response_video.php :

```
<?php 
//index.php
$TokenValue = 'my-token-value';
$myVideo = $Page->videofile->getViewValue() //my-Video-name-value
$iv = str_repeat('z', 16);
$path=openssl_encrypt($myVideo, "aes128", $TokenValue,0,$iv);
?>
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" id="myVideo" width="100%" height="550px" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload">
</video>
<script> 
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
vid.src='response_video.php?video_id=<?= $path?>&token=<?= $TokenValue?>';
vid.type = 'video/mp4';
</script>
```

Now my video src look like :
src"onlincu/response_video.php?video_id=AvpAkmjPf16HapWcRKDrdhRZWFeZTBox2LDHA3zeFnk="

Comment: Not sure, but it seems you want to avoid copy of your video. In that case, you're loosing your time. A screen capture tool will allow any one watching the video to get it, save it and share it. :/

Comment: @Peter But user can't take the original copy from my videos  that store on the host with this case, can he ? :(

Comment: @Peter i just want avoid users from looking to the original video path :$

Comment: If the user can see the video (and of course, he can!), he can use a screen capture software to "record" the video (see tools like Viemo Record or QuickTime on Mac).  If the goal is to prevent copy of the video, hidding the path is of no use.

Comment: @Peter yeah you are right' hidding the path is of no use ', Now my goal is for my site folder security , So I also wonder is there way to  avoid users from using  screen capture software :D , thanx for replay

Comment: "avoid users from using screen capture software" is not possible.